# Make phone calls using a computer through an Android phone, both connected by WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, calls, remote-control

I have a computer and Android phone connected by WiFi. I want to use my computer to make calls through the phone. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to also use the computer's microphone and speakers? Or do you simply want the computer to initiate the phone call, after which you'll physically hold your phone and talk as you normally would with a cell phone?

Comment: Its kinda obvious he wants to make call with pc mic. Did you find a solution? SideSync seems to work only for Samsung device, Remote Phone Call isnt really good app as Iv read some reviews, push bullet is nice but only for text messages not phone calls and Google Voice + hangouts is cool but it doesnt use your GSM provider but their own (paid) service AFAIK (so its not actually standard phone call).

Answer (score 2):

Remote Phone Call ([Click Here to View App on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=justPhone.remotePhone)) might help you with the GSM Calling via WIFI & BLUETOOTH.

Google VOICE & HANGOUT (Default app on android Phone) 
for PC you need plugin for installing HANGOUT..

Answer (score 1):

There is a startup in YCombinator's incubation center that is currently solving this very problem, they are called PushBullet.

https://www.pushbullet.com

Unfortunately though, their app is still a chrome extension, and it does not allow you to directly make calls from PC, your phone is connected with PC over LAN (read wifi), and it binds a port from your phone to the PC and allows you to add one more layer of abstraction between your phone and PC